# How to use grub as netboot menu with ipxe?

Tags: boot, pxe-boot, grub2, syslinux, ipxe

I am setting up a small office’s netboot solution. I have the machines configured to pxe boot an initial ipxe.efi nbp with an embedded ipxe script to chain request against a matchbox server for my k8s nodes. This is working great.

I need to extend this to present a menu so the user can choose to matchbox boot, or manually choose an OS. I understand ipxe itself supports a menu, but I could also chain boot into grub or syslinux.

Assuming I choose grub, I have a few questions:

- How do I set up my ipxe script to chain boot grub?
- Where should I get the grub assets, since it’s not tied to a particular OS?
- How do I host the grub config so the grub efi correctly finds it?
- It seems grub entries expect a kernel/initram specification rather than an iso, but all the OS I want to support booting like proxmox/Linux distros/memtest come in the form of isos. How do I support these?
- I’ve attempted to extract the contents of the iso, but I’m not sure how to correctly specify the filesystem given it’s hosted at a network location. How do I point the grub entry at the rest of the filesystem?

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers. You did not post any configuration nor logs or any of the requirements. please read carefully [ask]

Comment: Try this. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486829/how-to-boot-linux-kernel-from-network-through-grub2-console. In short you boot grubx64.efi directly and ensure it have network module. All other files (menu config, kernel) can be obtained via various network protocols such as NFS or HTTP.

Comment: "I need to extend this to present a menu so the user can choose to matchbox boot, or manually choose an OS."

This is a fairly explicit end state. I also asked specific pointed questions based on the research that I had done on the problem.

Comment: @kab00m thank you for your help. In the end, I was convinced through through research that I was really trying to build a network boot menu, and ipxe is specifically designed for this purpose. I learned some more ipxe scripting and got a raelly simple and great solution for what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: True, grub nowadays is too sophisticated for manual configuration.